# AngularJS - Display image on top of another image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am sorry if my codes are messy. I am trying to display image on top of another image in Ionic AngularJS. Basically, when user clicks the "apply" button, it will display the image "toilet.png" on top of the image "PathFindingMap.png".

In my navigation.html, I have the following code snippet:

```
    <button ng-click="apply()" type="button">Apply</button>
     <div style="width: 627px; height:975px; background-image: url('img/PathFindingMap.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:cover;">

     </div>
     <div ng-style="navigationStyleToilet[$index]" ng-repeat="o in arr"></div>
```

In my controller.js, I have the following code snippet:

```
 .controller('NavigationCtrl', function ($scope, NavigationService) {
$scope.myCategory = {}
$scope.apply = function () {
    $scope.arr = [];
    var strCategoryName = "Washroom";
     categoryInfo = NavigationService.fnGetCategoryInfo(strCategoryName);
    $scope.navigationStyleToilet = [];
    for (i = 0; i < categoryInfo.length; i++)
    {
        $scope.arr.push(i);
        var targetImageX = categoryInfo[i].X;
        var targetImageY = categoryInfo[i].Y;
        $scope.navigationStyleToilet[i] = {
            "z-index":"1",
            "position":"absolute",
            "width": "100px",
            "height": "100px",
            "top": targetImageY,
            "left":targetImageX,
            "background": "url('img/toilet.png')",
            "background-repeat": "no-repeat",     
      }
    }
}
})
```

In my servicesjs I have the following code snippet:

```
 .factory('NavigationService', function () {
 var ToiletCoordinates = new Array();
ToiletCoordinates[0] = { X: 16, Y: 100 };
 return {
        fnGetCategoryInfo: function (strCategoryName) {
            if (strCategoryName == "All Booth") {

            }
            else if (strCategoryName == "Washroom") {
                return ToiletCoordinates;
            }

        }
    }
  })
```

Unfortunately, the "toilet.png" image always display below the "PathFindingMap.png", regardless of the X and Y coordinates of the "toilet.png". I have tried many things but I still could not make the "toilet.png" displayed on top of the "PathFindingMap.png". It seems there is something wrong with my code. Can anyone tell me a way to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the z-index?

Comment: add div on top and bind image dynamically with using ng-show/ng-hide

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of CSS. To add image on the top of another image on button click, you can use ng-class attribute.

```js
var app = angular.module("ap", []);
app.controller("con", function($scope) {
  $scope.class = "imgagOnBottom";
  $scope.changeClass = function() {
    if ($scope.class === "imageOnBottom") $scope.class = "imageOnTop";
    else $scope.class = "imageOnBottom";
  };
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.imageOnTop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.imageOnBottom {
  /*whatever css you want.*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
  <div class="container" style="background-image:'PathFindingImage.png';">
        <img ng-class="class" / src="toliet.png">
  </div>
  <button ng-click="changeClass()">Change Class</button>
</body>
```

Comment: what are imageOnTop and imageOnBottom? I am confused

Comment: imageOnTop and imageOnBottom are style class name